# How to avoid errors of concatenating in Python 3

Tags: python, web-scraping, concatenation, python-3.6, string-concatenation

I'm having a problem of concatenation.

I tried to extract (Business Names) + (Phones Number) + (Addresses) + (websites url) and while everything works for the first 3 elements, I'm having an issue with "websites url".

In fact, when I extracted the content into a text file all the websites url were displayed straight to the top and did[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSyXA.png)n't match with the right businesses. When I printed into command prompt everything matched with the right businesses.

Hard to explain... So I attached two screenshots (insides links below). 
In the excel document, underlined in red you can see that urls is not at the right place and should be below.

Here is how I did concatenation :

```
try:
    print("list if contains websites")

    for i in range(0, min(len(freeNames),len(fullPhones),len(fullStreets),len(fullWebsites))):
            c = ' ~ '  + freeNames[i] + ' ~ ' + fullPhones[i] + ' ~ ' + fullStreets[i] + ' ~ '  + fullWebsites[i] + ' ~ '
            contents.append(c)
            print(c)
            trustedprotxtfile.write(c + '\n')
except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      pass

try:
    print("list if no websites")

        for i in range(min(len(freeNames),len(fullPhones),len(fullStreets),len(fullWebsites)), max(len(freeNames),len(fullPhones),len(fullStreets))):
            c = ' ~ '  + freeNames[i] + ' ~ ' + fullPhones[i] + ' ~ ' + fullStreets[i] + ' ~ '
            contents.append(c)
            print(c)
            trustedprotxtfile.write(c + '\n')
except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      pass
```

Do you have an idea how to fix this problem?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What is printing out in the Exception? (side note: you don't need to specify "0" as the first parameter of `range`, it is 0 by default; you also don't need `pass` at the end of `except`, you only need `pass` when there's nothing going on inside the block)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.
Here is what it is printed in terminal:

Skymark Renovations Nova Scotia
902-407-7171
2 Bluewater Road, Bedford NS B4B 1G7
http://www.futuregroupcompany.com/skymark-renovations.aspx

You have properly Business Name + Phone Number + Address + Website which is the right one in this cas.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using CSV format if you can, Python handles it easily as do most spreadsheet programs

```
import csv

# pull your arrays together for convenience
myarrs = (freeNames, fullPhones, fullStreets, fullWebsites)

# figure out which is the longest
nrows = max(len(a) for a in myarrs)

# pad everything to be the same length
padded = tuple(a + ['']*(nrows-len(a)) for a in myarrs)

# write it all out
csv.writer(trustedprotxtfile).writerows(zip(*padded))
```

Comment: Thanks Sam for your help.

I tried to use csv format but I still have the same issue with "websites" array.
The result is weird since I have a condition that says if there's no websites url put it blank.

I'll try other things and let you know. 
Thanks

Comment: what's the actual error/exception you're getting?  i.e. don't catch it, just let Python die, displaying you useful information in the stack trace

Comment: I didn't get any error message that's the problem. In cmd it print properly what I want, it's in the extract file that there is something wrong. I haven't got any list index out of range, so I don't get why it is not leaving "websites" blank.

Comment: you're going to have to post some more technical details; some sort of "minimum working example" would help.  either update the question or post another one…  the idea is so that people answering can just copy/paste code into a python interpreter to see the problem

Comment: I posted as answer the full code above. let me know if you need more detail. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[To answer Sam Mason]

Here is the full code I used:

This is the list of imported libraries: (re, selenium,lxml,urllib3,numpy,beautifulSoup)

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/gdeange1/dev/chromedriver")

trustedprotxtfile = open("/Users/gdeange1/Dev/trustedpros/test.txt", "w+", encoding='utf-8')

links = ['ns/halifax',]

for l in links:
    link = "https://trustedpros.ca/" + l

```
driver = browser.get("https://trustedpros.ca/" + l)


page0 = requests.get(link)
soup0 = bs(page0.content, "lxml")


nextpages = soup0.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'paging-sec'})


pagination = []

if nextpages:
    for ul in nextpages:
        for li in ul.find_all('li'):
            liText = li.text
            if liText != '-':
                pagination.append(int(liText)) 


maxpagination = max(pagination)



freeNames = [] 
fullPhones = []
fullStreets = []
fullWebsites = []


i = 0
while i < maxpagination:
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1    


    try:
        inputElement = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="final-search"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a')
        allLinksTim = [];
        for url in inputElement:
            allLinksTim.append(url.get_attribute("href"))
    except:
        pass


    for eachLink in allLinksTim:
        driver = browser.get(eachLink)
        page = requests.get(eachLink)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        soup = bs(page.content, "lxml")


        try:
            namess = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('name-alt')
            if len(namess) > 0:

                for name in namess:
                    freeNames.append(name.text)
                    print(name.text)
            else:

                names = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('name-altimg')
                for names1 in names:
                    freeNames.append(names1.text)
                    print(names1.text)
        except:
            print("Error while trying to get the names")
            pass


        try:
            phones = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('taptel')
            if phones:
                for phone in phones:
                    fullPhones.append(phone.text)
                    print(phone.text)
            else:
                print("No phones found")
        except:
            print('Error while trying to get the phones')
            pass


        try:
            streets = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('address')
            if streets:
                for street in streets:
                    fullStreets.append(street.text)
                    print(street.text)
            else:
                print("No street address found")
        except:
            print('Error while trying to get the streets')
            pass


        try:
            websites = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'contact-prom'})
            #print('Entered the Div!')
            if websites:
                for div in websites:
                    for url in div.find_all('a'):
                        if url.has_attr('target'):
                            fullWebsites.append(url['href'])
                            print(url['href'])
            else:
                print("No websites found")

        except:
            print('Error while trying to get the websites')
            pass


        browser.back()

    inputElement = browser.find_element_by_class_name('next-page')
    inputElement.click()


contents = []      


print("Size of free names: ", len(freeNames))
print("Size of full phones: ", len(fullPhones))
print("Size of full streets: ", len(fullStreets))
print("Size of full websites: ", len(fullWebsites))



try:
    print("list with everything")

    for i in range(min(len(freeNames),len(fullPhones),len(fullStreets),len(fullWebsites))):
        c = ' ~ '  + freeNames[i] + ' ~ ' + fullPhones[i] + ' ~ ' + fullStreets[i] + ' ~ '  + fullWebsites[i] + ' ~ '
        contents.append(c)
        print(c)
        trustedprotxtfile.write(c + '\n')
except:
    print('not working 1')
    pass

try:
    print("list without websites")

    for i in range(min(len(freeNames),len(fullPhones),len(fullStreets),len(fullWebsites)), max(len(freeNames),len(fullPhones),len(fullStreets))):
        c = ' ~ '  + freeNames[i] + ' ~ ' + fullPhones[i] + ' ~ ' + fullStreets[i] + ' ~ '
        contents.append(c)
        print(c)
        trustedprotxtfile.write(c + '\n')
except:
    print('not working')
    pass
```

print ('[Crawling is now over, thanks for waiting !]')
trustedprotxtfile.close()